# how to select variable in sqlit3 table

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I tried to get some variable from my SQLite table for some reasons  I get an error that the column "user1" is no in the table

what I try to do is go to my table users from there get the user_id value-form where username in the same table equal to the value user1

```
sql.cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = {}".format('user1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using normal Python string formatting, your query is this.

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = user1
```

Note the lack of quotes. `where username = user1` is where the column username equals the column user1.

You need to quote your values.

```
SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = 'user1'
```

But ***do not treat SQL like strings***. From the [Python sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)...

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program vulnerable to an [SQL injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (see https://xkcd.com/327/ for humorous example of what can go wrong).

Instead, [use bind parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute). They treat the query more like passing parameters to a function.

```
sql.cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?", 'user1')
```

Comment: hi I forget to mention that the user1 is variable that gets the string from the other  source

Comment: and if it was the case  `code` sql.cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?", (user,))

Comment: @user13099369 Passing a literal string or a variable makes no difference. You don't need a tuple for a single argument, though it doesn't hurt. `sql.cur.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?", user)`